# How to install lshw on Kali Linux (debian)

Tags: kali-linux

**Answered** **Closed**

OK, here's the situation::

I am using Kali Linux (Debian 32-bit (Gnome 3.28.2)) on a vbox VM. I'm also using Linux Mint 19 on another vbox VM.

I tried using lshw command in the Kali Linux terminal, but it pretty much told me "haha you idiot FAIL." So, then I knew I'd have to install it. But before that, I knew I should probably search the available packages first.

When I use the following code to search for lshw:

```
sudo apt-cache search lshw
```

and

```
sudo apt-cache search lshw-gtk
```

Mint 19 found the lshw and lshw-gtk packages just fine, however, Kali didn't find anything. Both of them found apache2 just fine.

I tried to install lshw despite the search finding nothing by using

```
apt-get install lshw
```

But that told me

```
E: Unable to locate package lshw
```

I didn't need to install lshw on Mint 19, because when I tested it to see if it was pre-installed it worked fine. It's wasn't pre-installed on Kali though.

Now, I don't know what to do to get lshw installed on my Debian Kali Linux.

Comment: You could just try copying the `usr/bin/lshw` binary over from Mint. It doesn't seem to have any tricky dependencies.

Comment: you should not call Kali Linux : Debian Kali Linux, using deb or debiand repo as the main packages in the OS doesn't make your distribution a Debian. please provide the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` it seems your Kali install is no longer correct. You should also provide the output of `apt update` and `apt upgrade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may need to install it manually. Here's the lshw github page: https://github.com/lyonel/lshw

Comment: This method worked, not not for making or installing the GUI. But I won't complain because I have working cmd lshw.